# Required custom formatter for speech to text google service

Tags: google-api, google-speech-to-text-api

In project we are using [speech-to-text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength#speech-context-strength-java) google service.

It brings a lot of advantages and simplifies audio processing on one hand, on other hand we heed special data formatting for example:

**Field Type : Money**

```
Current Output : no payment due
Expected Output : $0

Current Output : no outstanding balance
Expected Output : $0
```

**Field Type : Date**

```
Current Output : May 1st 2020
Expected Output : 05/01/2020

Current Output : May 1st 2020.
Expected Output : 05/01/2020

Current Output : June 1st 2020.
Expected Output : 06/01/2020

Current Output : March 13th.
Expected Output : 03/13/2020 (automatically infer the year)
```

We've tried to look at [class-token](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens), but this approach did not provide tool to cover our needs.
We've checked the API few times, researching behavior - result still the same.
I believe that we've missed something and hope for community help.

### P.S.

Our project language is `java` and we believe that in scope of the issue it is not so important.